# how i can show object in gridview or in any usful control

Tags: c#

i have an class hwo two property of is object
 public class EventDetail
    {
        private Int64 logID;

```
    public Int64 LogID
    {
        get { return logID; }
        set { logID = value; }
    }
    private Object logedObject;

    public Object LogedObject
    {
        get { return logedObject; }
        set { logedObject = value; }
    }

}
```

how i can bind any collection of this class to grideview or approperiate control